# Mongomapper regex search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongomapper

In my rails application I am searching for company name and I am using mongodb for backend.
My query for finding company is

```
@companies = Company.where(name: /#{params[:search]}/i).all
```

In my db I have company having name "ABC&D Services Inc. (Atlanta Project)" and When I am trying to search this company with giving string "ABC&D Services Inc." it will not return any result. Also if I am trying to search with string "ABC&D Services Inc.(" it gives me error **end pattern with unmatched parenthesis**

Anyone have idea how to solve this kind of issues with reg-ex. End user can perform search with any input so there is way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regexp.escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) escapes special characters:

```
@companies = Company.where(name: /#{Regexp.escape(#{params[:search]})}/i).all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@companies = Company.where(name: /#{Regexp.escape(params[:search])}/i)
```